# jQuery UI autocomplete jsonp mapping response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jsonp

I am trying to use the autocomplete from jqueryUI. When i alert the response i get the following : `([ { "id": "test", "label": "test", "value": "test" } ]);`

but when i try to map the result the dropdown result is empty. here is my code:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    function log( message ) {
        $( "<div/>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
        $( "#log" ).scrollTop( 0 );
    }

    $( "#city" ).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost/jQuery/development-bundle/demos/autocomplete/search3.php",
                jsonp: "jsonp_callback",
                data: {
                    featureClass: "P",
                    style: "full",
                    maxRows: 12,
                    name_startsWith: request.term
                },
                success: function( data ) {
                    alert(data);
                    response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                        return {
                            label: item.label,
                            value: item.value
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            log( ui.item ?
                "Selected: " + ui.item.label :
                "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
        },
        open: function() {
            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
        },
        close: function() {
            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

my server side script uses  the following code:

```
echo $_GET['jsonp_callback'] . '(' . $data . ');';
```

Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this line

```
url: "http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON?jsonp_callback=?",
```

and datatype  also

```
dataType: 'jsonp',
```

instead of

```
url: "http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON",
```

Comment: My Fault copied the wrong code i use this url there is my script located that get's the data and uses the echo $_GET['jsonp_callback'] . '(' . $data . ');';  i use this url http://localhost/jQuery/development-bundle/demos/autocomplete/search3.php

Comment: I have changed the url to : http://localhost/jQuery/development-bundle/demos/autocomplete/search3.php?jsonp_callback=?

now is my reponse: ?([ { "id": "Jimmy", "label": "Jimmy", "value": "Jimmy" } ]);

but still the dropdown is empty